# Can I access the list of installed packages on Android from C++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I would like to examine the list of installed packages from within C++ code on Android.  I don't want to use JNI to invoke the regular Android package manager.  Ideally I could just list the contents of some directory...?

Comment: Not unless you're rooted, for directories.  Of course you can do it easily through JNI.

Comment: Cool. Let's assume the device is rooted. In what directory would I find all the .apk files?

Comment: User installed apps are in */data/app* and preinstalled are in */system/app*.

Comment: @nikita the system for got split in two a Weedle back. App and priv_app

Comment: Try executing in the environment the command: `pm list packages` and read (later parse) the output.

Comment: Using "adb shell" I am unable to view '/data/app' on either of my devices (one is rooted, one is not).  Says insufficient permissions in both cases.

Comment: Didn't realize I had to "su" first.  Although that kinda ruins the test in my case.